# Tag wiki reputation bug

Tags: support, tags

I assume this is a bug, tag wiki editing now requires 20,000 reputation?

https://apple.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit-tag-wiki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a bug, if you don't have 20k rep then suggest an edit and it will be peer reviewed.

Comment: OK thanks, it was 1.5k last week, hence the question.